# CodeDom referencing System.Management

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, codedom

No matter what I try I am unable to reference System.Management in to my codedom project, I have tried

```
Dim assemblyReferences = New String() {"System.Drawing.dll",
                                                "System.Data.dll",
                                                    "System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll",
                                                    "System.Deployment.dll",
                                                    "System.Management.dll",
                                                    "System.Net.dll",
                                                    "System.Net.Http.dll",
                                                    "System.dll",
                                                    "System.Core.dll",
                                                    "mscorlib.dll",
                                                    "System.Windows.Forms.dll",
                                                    "System.Xml.dll",
                                                    "System.Xml.Linq.dll"}
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblyReferences)
```

Among other methods such as using it implicitly and importing it at the top of the class

Answer (score 0):

I have found it to work using both...

```
var compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
compileUnit.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
compileUnit.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Management.dll");
```

...and...

```
var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[] {"System.dll", "System.Management.dll" }, "TestAssembly.dll", true);
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, compileUnit);
```

`System.dll` is required by `System.Management.dll`

The code snippet I used was:

```
var compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
compileUnit.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
compileUnit.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Management.dll");
var codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace("ClassLibrary1");
compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(codeNamespace);
var testClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("TestClass");
var declaration = new CodeMemberField(typeof(System.Management.ManagementClass), "managementClass");
testClass.Members.Add(declaration);
codeNamespace.Types.Add(testClass);
```

I compiled it with:

```
using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic"))
{
    var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[] {"System.dll", "System.Management.dll" }, "TestAssembly.dll", true);
    var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, compileUnit);

    return results;
}
```

Sorry the example is in C#.